# How to print the following content in tabular format using shell (or) awk

Tags: awk

Have following content in a text which i got from query:

```
    EMC Documentum idql - Interactive document query interface
    (c) Copyright EMC Corp., 1992 - 2013
    All rights reserved.
    Client Library Release 7.1.0200.0207


Connecting to Server 
1> 2> ID       Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
128993434  Status                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
(1 row affected)
```

Requirement:- Print out as below in tabular form

```
ID             Name
128993434    Status
```

Was trying to print the content using awk as below:

```
awk '{if($0 !~ /--/){sub(/^ +/,"");print $0}}' output_status.txt
```

which is not giving me result what i want.

Please guide me.

Comment: Try starting simpler from `awk '/--/ {print $9}'` and see if you can build a solution from there. Once you get the output from `awk` right then try piping the output to `column`

Comment: Have you explored the documentation for `idql` to see if it can produce the formatting you want?  That would probably be far simpler and much more flexible than hacking an `awk` script onto its output, and give better results—if it's supported by the tool.

Comment: [One web resource](https://blog.dbi-services.com/idql-and-its-column-output/) says: "Unlike sqlplus, idql has no column formatting ... Needless to say, having a nicely displayed output is not possible within idql." and ends with an awk script that appears to format things nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Done by below command

```
awk '/Name/||/Status/{print $0}' filename| sed "s/-//g"| sed '/^$/d'| sed "s/1> 2> //g"| sed '/^$/d'|sed '/^$/d'
```

output

```
ID       Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
128993434  Status
```